# C# serial port converter read data via ip

Tags: c#, tcp, serial-port, converters

I have a tibbo device for converting to serial port to IP. With a program like putty I can connect the device successfully and the device is working.

I want to develop little C# windows form application for listening this device but I can not find any way. Application get data from serial port via ip over tibbo serial to IP converter devices. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Tibbo Device Server Toolkit](http://tibbo.com/soi/software.html) and map your tibbo device to a COM Port. If you need more help with SerialPort Communication read this article [Serial Port Communication for beginners](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners)

Example Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SerialPortExample
{
  class SerialPortProgram
  {
    // Create the serial port with basic settings
    private SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
      // Instatiate this class
      new SerialPortProgram();
    }

    private SerialPortProgram()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Incoming Data:");

      // Attach a method to be called when there
      // is data waiting in the port's buffer
      port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

      // Begin communications
      port.Open();

      // Enter an application loop to keep this thread alive
      Application.Run();
    }

    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
      // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
      Console.WriteLine(port.ReadExisting());
    }
  }
}
```